# Managing VueJS Component library css

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am building VueJS Component library which include vue-element and some other third party libraries.
I am including my library in my main project. 
But my main project contain same third party libraries (vue-element) for some other forms components. 
So the question is how to manage third party css. As at the moment I am duplicating vue-element css files (one time its include in main my project and second from my library css)

Comment: please share you project structure and third party css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must treat `vue-element` as an external dependency for your library. Explicitly state it as a dependency. It means your library should assume that calling project i.e. the **main project** will load the CSS prior to loading CSS of your library.

This is how most projects structure CSS. Your HTML file would be something like this:

```
<!-- External CSS -->
<link href="vue-element/dist/style.css" />

<!-- Library CSS -->
<link href="path-to-your-library/dist/style.css" />
```

Comment: But <link href="path-to-your-library/dist/style.css" /> already contains 'vue-element/dist/style.css' As I am importing it in the library (as I want library to be stable if someone wants to use it in another project)

Comment: That's the point. Your library CSS should not contain external CSS. Leave it to the caller application to include in their application if they wish to use your library. Imagine how it happens in Node.js with peerDependencies.